# How does what3words build a grid of squares on the surface of the Earth?

Tags: mercator, what3words

What3words built a grid of squares of 3m2 on the earth. Does anyone know what is the algorithm ?

I started with this method: the range of longitude is [-180, 180] and the range of latitude is [-90,90]. If you cut them into equal intervals, you can have almost perfect squares near equator, but near the poles, they arenot squares, are they ?

---

After Gary's answer. I still want some precisions.

If between -85° and 85° (latitudes), the squares are in a grid, do I have to assume that the number of squares at a any latitude is the same (for me, when I say a grid, for each side of the square, there should be one and only one square)? If so, at the equator, we can have a square of 3mx3m, but at latitude 85°, it is a 0.26m x 0.26m then. (Because the parallel at latitude 85° is cos(85°) shorter.)

So, do I have to assume that it is not a **perfect** grid , since the area of the square always 3m x 3m at any latitude between -85° and 85°. But when I tried to zoom into a what3word map, I always see a perfect grid. How is it possible? Is it possible to see some deformations, directly on a map ?

@Gary, is it possible to see the deformations (near the poles) you mentionned in a map ? (it seems that we can't see on a google map).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're on the right lines. The what3words grid is algorithmically generated to be nearly exactly 3m by 3m to within a couple of centimetres at latitudes between -85º and +85º. Between +/- 85º north and south and the poles, the notional grid squares expand the closer to the poles you get and at their largest extent are ~4.5m by ~4.5m with some deformation at the poles.

It's not easy to visualise the deformation, hence my use of the word *notional* in the previous paragraph. The datum that what3words works with is [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) and the algorithm at the heart of what3words "understands" this and so it's always algorithmically able to *map* a 3 word address to coordinates and vice versa. But most web maps, Google's included, are displaying that data once it's been (re)projected CRS; Google uses [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/). It's really challenging to display the deformation as you're working against how the underlying mapping API wants you to work. The closest you'll get is the slight shifts in the *notional* grid that occur as you move north of south from the meridian, as shown near [evens.response.fishes](http://w3w.co/evens.response.fishes) if you zoom in enough that the grid will be shown.

[image: evens.response.fishes]

(disclaimer - in my day job I work for what3words)

Comment: Would this addressing system work better with a moving datum? i.e. each 3x3 block has it's own datum at the center?